# jQuery to monitor links to see if they are hovered over, if they are go up 3 parents and add css/class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have lots of links on my page with the HTML format of:

```
<div class="heading-column">
    <div class="heading-container">
        <h2 class="heading-item">
            <a href="/find/">Find</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently we have some animations happening when they hover over the `heading-column` element, but they should actually only happen when hovering over the `a` hyperlink.

I'm trying to figure out how to create some jQuery to monitor all hyperlinks, if one with the class of `.heading-item a` is hovered over for it to update its parent 3 higher (`.heading-column`) by adding the css of `pointer-events: auto;` but as soon as the mouse stops hovering, this css rule should be deleted so that the `pointer-events: none;` stops the `.heading-column` animation/hover from happening

I'd greatly appreciate some help

Comment: `pointer-events : none` would also affect the descendant `<a>`  so not sure what you are asking really makes sense

Comment: @charlietfl But I can add pointer-events to the hyperlinks, so it will still work as intended...

Comment: Never tried it but sure seems to me that if parent has no pointer events then a child wouldn't either

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
$(".heading-column a").hover(function(){
  // In
  $(this).closest(".heading-column").css("pointer-events", "none");
}, function(){
  // Out
  $(this).closest(".heading-column").css("pointer-events", "auto");
});
```

Reference: https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Might consider adding and removing a Class too.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps -

[https://codepen.io/VweMWoz](https://codepen.io/pranavraghaw1/pen/VweMWoz)

```
const tl = gsap.timeline({paused: true});

tl.from(
    ".gsap-swipe",
    {
      y: 20,
      x: 20,
      rotate: -40,
      duration: 3,
      transformOrigin: '30% 80%',
      ease: Elastic.easeOut.config(1, 0.5),
    }, 0
  )
  .fromTo(
    ".swipe",
    {
      xPercent: -100
    },
    {
      duration: 1,
      xPercent: 100,
      ease: Sine.easeInOut,
      stagger: {
        each: 0.15
      }
    }, 0
  )
  .from(
    ".maskSwipe",
    {
      xPercent: -100,
      ease: Sine.easeInOut
    },
    0.4
  )
  .from(
    "#hello",
    {
      duration: 1.5,
      drawSVG: "0%"
    },
    1
  )
  .from(
    ".swoop",
    {
      duration: 2,
      drawSVG: "0%"
    },
    1
  )
  .from(
    ".line",
    {
      drawSVG: "0%",
      duration: 0.5,
      stagger: {
        each: 0.2
      }
    },
    1
  )
  .from(
    ".shape",
    {
      scale: 0,
      duration: 1.3,
      transformOrigin: "50% 50%",
      rotate: '+=random(-60, 60)',
      ease: Elastic.easeOut.config(1, 0.8),
      stagger: {
        each: 0.2
      }
    },
    0.2
  );

// ScrubGSAPTimeline(tl);

let hover = document.querySelector('.js-hover');

hover.addEventListener('mouseover', playTl);
hover.addEventListener('mouseout', resetTl);

function playTl(){
  tl.timeScale(1.25).restart();
}

function resetTl(){
  tl.progress(0).pause();
}
```